# FileNotFound EACCESS when opening file Android Marshmallow

Tags: android, file, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

During automated tests for my product, I push files to the apps private directory and `chmod` the file so that the app can access it. On APIs < Marshmallow, this was fine and the apps never had an issue accessing files.

Now, on some files, I get the following logs when trying to open it:

```
W/System.err(7669): Caused by: 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/foo/foo.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) 09-28 18:20:56.724: 
W/System.err(7669):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452) 09-28 18:20:56.724: 
W/System.err(7669):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76) 09-28 18:20:56.724: 
W/System.err(7669):     at android.app.ContextImpl.openFileInput(ContextImpl.java:384) 09-28 18:20:56.724: 
W/System.err(7669):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileInput(ContextWrapper.java:177) 09-28 18:20:56.724: 
W/System.err(7669): Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) 09-28 18:20:56.724: 
W/System.err(7669):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method) 09-28 18:20:56.724: 
W/System.err(7669):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186) 09-28 18:20:56.724: 
W/System.err(7669):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438) 09-28 18:20:56.716: 
W/pool-5-thread-1(8279): type=1400 audit(0.0:57): avc: denied { search } for name="files" dev="mtdblock1" ino=7314 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
```

How can I fix?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Android Marshmallow has adopted the extended file attributes of its underlying OS, SELinux (Security Enhanced Linux) so there are going to be problems pushing files and preferences willy-nilly betwixt apps through the shell and not through an app that has permissions on the FS.

First, ensure that you `chmod` the file properly. Then, ensure that the file is owned correctly as well. You can check what a normal file's owner and group look like by doing an `ls -la file` then changing the group of your file in question to what you found from the previous command by `chgrp user.group file`

```
$ ls -la  
drwxrwxrwx u0_a69   u0_a69            2015-09-28 18:20 existing_file
drwxrwxrwx root   root            2015-09-28 18:20 file    
$ chown u0_a69.u0_a69 file
```

If neither of those work, check the extended file attributes by `ls -Z file` and go read https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Security_context?rd=SELinux/SecurityContext to understand what you're looking at, then use `chcon some:extended:security:attributes file` to change your files permissions.

```
$ ls -Z 
 drwxrwx--x u0_a69   u0_a69 u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 existing_file    
 drwxrwx--x u0_a69   u0_a69 u: file
$ chcon u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 file
```

If that still doesn't work, there's a binary in `/system/bin` called `setenforce` that disables the extended file system security of Marshmallow's underlying SELinux.

Call `setenforce permissive` from a rooted shell and your app will be able to access the files it needs. This may mask bugs so use with caution.

```
$ setenforce permissive
```

Answer (score 1):

In Android Manifest file try putting

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

And in runtime you could check the permission granted or directly grant access to all permissions in your settings->App->Permission and see whether it works...

```
public boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                if(checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
```